# Elliptic curve points with the same $y$-coordinate

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $nP = (x,y)$ be a point on elliptic curve $E: x^3+ax+b=y^2$ modulo a prime $p$. If I want to create all points with the same $x$ coordinate the process is simple, $nP, -nP$ is the full list.

If I want to create all the points with the same $y$ coordinate, what should my construction be?

That is, assuming $x^3+ax+b = y^2$ has $3$ solutions for a particular $y$, and $nP$ is one such solution, construct the other two solutions $n_1P$ and $n_2P$.

By colinearity we get that the sum of $n,n_1,n_2$ must be $0$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You have a cubic equation $x^3 +ax+b-y^2=0$ of which you know one solution, so it drops down to a quadratic equation, which is easy to solve. Often it has no solution. Even if it has, there is no reason that the points that you obtain are linearly dependent, i.e. they may not be of the form $mP$ for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sure, but under the assumption that there are multiple solutions and $P$ generates, they must lie on the same horizontal line. I would guess by fundamental theorem of algebra $n_1, n_2$ must be ``equidistant" from $n$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, you want to determine $n_1$ and $n_2$ assuming they exist. But that depends on your choice of $P$ and changing that will change $n_i$ in a way that they are not "equidistant" (whatever you mean by that).

Comment: Yes, I want to find $n_1$ and $n_2$ when they exist. In the easy $x$-coordinate constant case we have the invariant that $n + n_1 = 0$ which immediately gives $n,-n$ as solutions. It would be nice to have an invariant for the $y$-coordinate case.

Since $n + n_1 + n_2 = 0$ we only need one more equation and we can solve for $n_1,n_2$.

Comment: Maybe its something like, let $a^3 = 1$ modulo the order of the EC group, then $n, an, a^2n$ are the solutions?

Comment: There is no simple procedure. I'm pretty sure you would just have to search for the right multiple. It's not too hard to prove that there is no constant $a$ depending on the elliptic curve $E$ such that $n P $ and $a nP$ have the same $y$ coordinate for more than $O( \sqrt{p})$ values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too long for a comment: there is a (very) special case where this has a convenient answer.

Let $q$ be an odd prime power, and consider the elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{F}_q: y^3 = x^3 + b$ of $j$-invariant $0$ (for $b \not= 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$).  Now $E$ has an automorphism $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (\zeta_3 x, y)$, where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$, and $\alpha^2 + \alpha + [1] = [0]$ in $\operatorname{End}(E)$ (because $\alpha^3 = [1]$, but $\alpha \not= [1]$).

The orbits of points in $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ under $\langle\alpha\rangle$ are precisely the sets of points with the same $y$-coordinate.

Now suppose that $P$ is a point in $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ such that $\alpha(\langle P\rangle) = \langle P \rangle$: that is, such that $\alpha$ restricts to an endomorphism of the subgroup $\langle P \rangle$.  Let $N$ be the order of $P$.  The endomorphisms of $\langle P \rangle$ are $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, so $\alpha$ must act on $\langle P \rangle$ as some eigenvalue $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, and given $\alpha^2 + \alpha + [1] = [0]$ we must have $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$: that is, $\lambda$ is a primitive $3$-rd root of unity mod $N$.  Now if $[n]P$, $[n_1]P$, and $[n_2]P$ all have the same $y$-coordinate, then $\{n,n_1,n_2\} = \{n,\lambda n, \lambda^2 n\}$ (as subsets of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$).